# CEP for monitoring system

Tags: java, complex-event-processing

I'm interested what are the ways to implement CEP(Complex event processing) system for monitoring. I need to monitor many devices and I need to compare the result using event filters.

Are there any modern architectures for this specific case?

Comment: It would be better if you could explain what sort of systems going to be integrated. For an instance you can use something like Siddhi as a library in your system or else you can have a CEP node like WSO2 CEP which can process internally.

Answer (score 0):

For CEP any of (sorted alphabetically) Drools, Esper+EsperHA, Siddhi.
In combination with CEP for distributing of processing such as Flink, Kafka, RabbitMQ, Storm when needed.

Answer (score 0):

As they mention above, there are several architectures or technologies to use.

I've worked lately with Apache Flink and they new integration with CEP and I can say it was pretty straightforward and easy to use, the examples helped me understanding it and in our team is the main tool we use now for event processing. Specifically, RFID EPC events.

Give it a try, I would totally recommend it.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/libs/cep.html